# How to get data from a form on a wordpress site?

Tags: plugins, forms

I am building a plugin that reads the data submitted from a form and sends it to a remote database.

How can I get the data from the form fields?

Answer (score 0):

**WordPress Hooks Method**

If the form is created with a plugin (like Contact Form 7 or Gravity Forms) you can use the available hooks:

CF7: wpcf7_before_send_mail

GF: gform_after_submission

This should cover the majority of WordPress Websites. On both  hooks you can access the transmitted form fields and send them to your own script.

**jQuery Method**

If you simply want to access all possible forms and Plugins i only See the solution of writing a jQuery script that sends the data via AJAX but i would not recommend this approach as i think it could easily lead to conflicts.

```
$("#myform").submit(function(event) {
  // prevent form from sending
  event.preventDefault();

  // get the data
  var paramter1 = $("#a-field").val();

  $.ajax({
    url:   "url/to/your/script.php", 
    type:  "GET",
    data: {
        'parameter1' : paramter1
    },
    success: function(result){
      // data transmitted -> now send the original form
      $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
    }
  });
});
```

**Reference:**

1. http://hookr.io/plugins/contact-form-7/4.7/hooks/#index=a
2. https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_after_submission/

Comment: Unfortunately, the form is made with "Themify Builder" and I cannot find a hook on their website. Could you please tell me more about the jQuery script approach?

Comment: i updated the answer with a jquery snippet